# Can't float left when filtering items in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on this page:
http://broadcasted.tv/fallshow.php

Basically, I'd like the images to float to the left when they're being filtered but they won't. They did about 15 minutes ago and I made some changes and it won't anymore. I'm not sure what I did or why it won't float anymore.  They all have the proper css.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

JS

```
<script src="livefilter.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

    $('#search_input').fastLiveFilter('.two');
});
</script>
```

and HTML

```
<div class="row main-wrapper watchlist-left">
 <div class="two columns float-left"></div>
 <div class="two columns float-left"></div>
 <div class="two columns float-left"></div>
 <div class="two columns float-left"></div>
 <div class="two columns float-left"></div>
 <div class="two columns float-left"></div>
 <div class="two columns float-left"></div>
 <div class="two columns float-left"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you filter your items, you're just making the undesirable items smaller, you're not actually hiding them. They are actually still floated left, but you have all the undesirable list items at `1px by {width}`.

You need to take `min-height: 1px` off of `.column, .columns`